# Removing a custom form type through terminal Symfony4

Tags: php, forms, types, symfony4, delete-file

I created a custom form type through the terminal in symfony4, but it doesn't work like I expected it to do. I figured out how to solve my problem without using the form type so my DishType isn't necessary anymore. But it is linked to my class 'Dish' (I had to give the class reference when creating it through the terminal) so when I delete the file I get this error:

```
    Could not load type "App\Entity\Dish": class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface".
```

That's right because I've deleted the file and my Dish should not implement this.

So my thoughts were 'I've created it through the terminal, so I should be able to delete it through the terminal as well', but I can't figure out how.

Is there a different way to do this or can I indeed do it through the terminal?

Anyone who can help me ???

Comment: The easiest way would be to just revert whatever was changed. Either your repository of choice or a simple remove of the files might help. But the given error message does not really look related to what you are stating - have you declared your entity class as a form type?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony4 MakerBundle hasn't got option to remove once created files.

In your case you should remove src/Form/DishType.php file and... that's it.
But, your issue is not related with it.

**Probably somewhere in your Controller class you use reference to Dish entity class**

```
$form = $this->createForm(Dish::class);
```

instead of Dish form class

```
$form = $this->createForm(DishType::class);
```

**So if you don't use Dish form anymore you should find where you're using**

```
$this->createForm(Dish::class)
```

and delete this line and you can optionally clean your application cache

```
php bin/console c:c
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it!
I had deleted it correctly but somehow this piece of code tried to find the formtype:

```
    property: 'dish'
    type: collection
    upload_new: true
    type_options: 
        entry_type: 'App\Entity\Dish'
        required: true
        by_reference: false
    multiple: true
```

So I changed it to:

```
    property: 'dish'
    upload_new: true
    type_options: 
        class: 'App\Entity\Dish' 
        required: true
    multiple: true
```

And this works! I think the `type: collection` linked to the formtype that I removed.